# How to make Polygon in SymPy from a list of vertices

Tags: python, sympy

I want to use SymPy to create a Polygon with *n* faces and calculate all parameters.

The easy form is

```
from sympy import Polygon
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1), (3, 0)]
Polygon(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)

Polygon(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(5, 1), Point(0, 1))
```

but I want to use *n* points from a list, for example

```
p = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1), (3, 0)]
Polygon(p)
```

But this form and similar is not validated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question does not have much to do with sympy, rather it is about basic python syntax. Generally you should check the tutorials for the language before asking this type of question. Stackoverflow preaches "rubber duck debugging" en.wikipaedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by putting an asterisk in front of the list of parameters to expand it out, like so:

```
p=[(0, 0), (1, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1), (3, 0)]
Polygon(*p)
```

This will be equivalent to calling `Polygon((0, 0), (1, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1), (3, 0))`.